# Sort array by last name

Tags: javascript, sorting

Hi I have an array or users and courses.

I need to sort by the users last name, however i can't seem to figure it out what I need to do to split the name.

Below is what I have that currently only sorts by first name.

```
const userarray = [
    { course: "Math", user: "Steve Lewis" },
    { course: "English", user: "James Rollo" },
    { course: "IT", user: "Suzanne Collins" }
]

userarray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.user.toLowerCase().localeCompare(
        b.user.toLowerCase()
    );
});

console.log(userarray);
```

Comment: how are you going to sort this one: `{user:"Steve Lewis" },{user:"Alice Lewis" }` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to split the name using space to get words. Assuming last word will be the last name, you can get it using `pop()` and use it for sorting

```js
const userarray = [{course: "Math",user: "Steve Lewis"},{course: "English",user: "James Rollo"},{course: "IT",user: "Suzanne Collins"}]

const getLastName = (name) => name.split(' ').pop().toLowerCase()
userarray.sort(function(a, b) {
  const lnameA = getLastName(a.user)
  const lnameB = getLastName(b.user)
  return lnameA.localeCompare(lnameB);
});

console.log(userarray);
```

To print in the way you need, you can use following code:

```js
const userarray = [{course: "Math",user: "Steve Lewis"},{course: "English",user: "James Rollo"},{course: "IT",user: "Suzanne Collins"}]

const getLastName = (name) => name.split(' ').pop().toLowerCase()
userarray.sort(function(a, b) {
  const lnameA = getLastName(a.user)
  const lnameB = getLastName(b.user)
  return lnameA.localeCompare(lnameB);
});

console.log(userarray.map(({
  user,
  course
}) => `${user} is studying ${course}`));
```

---

As rightly commented by [gog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3494774/gog)

> how are you going to sort this one: {user:"Steve Lewis" },{user:"Alice Lewis" } ?

Adding fallback to sort first name as well

```js
const userarray = [{course: "Math",user: "Steve Lewis"},{course: "English",user: "James Rollo"},{course: "IT",user: "Suzanne Collins"}, {course: "Math",user: "Alice Lewis"}]

const getNames = (name) => {
  const names = name.split(' ');
  const lname = names.pop();
  return [names.join(' '), lname].map((name) => name.toLowerCase())
}
userarray.sort(function(a, b) {
  const [fnameA, lnameA] = getNames(a.user)
  const [fnameB, lnameB] = getNames(b.user)
  return lnameA.localeCompare(lnameB) || fnameA.localeCompare(fnameB);
});

console.log(userarray);
```

Comment: How would I output this to say Steve Lewis is studying Math etc...

Comment: Instead of console.log - add a string to a variable Name is studying Course

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` to get the first name

```js
const userarray = [
    { course: "Math", user: "Steve Lewis" },
    { course: "English", user: "James Rollo" },
    { course: "IT", user: "Suzanne Collins" }
]

userarray.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aname = a.user.split(" ").pop();
    var bname = b.user.split(" ").pop();
    return aname.toLowerCase().localeCompare(
        bname.toLowerCase()
    );
});

console.log(userarray);
```

Comment: A small suggestion, before you change your approach in an answer, make sure to check other answers. Your changes can make someone's answer void.

Comment: @Rajesh,sorry for that,and after checking I found my answer is same to you,and I upvote your answer

Comment: No need to be sorry. And its not because of my answer. Its a general suggestion, be it question or answer. Edits can change context

Comment: How would I output this to say Steve Lewis is studying Math etc...